# Property 'revertedWith' does not exist on type 'Assertion'

Tags: javascript, hardhat, mocha, waffle, chai

I'm running a test using waffle in hardhat.

```js
import { assert, expect } from "chai"
.
.
.

  it("can only be changed through governance", async () => {
    await expect(box.store(55)).to.be.revertedWith("Nope, you bad")
  })
```

However when I run tests, I run into:

```
test/unit/testflow.test.ts:31:39 - error TS2339: Property 'revertedWith' does not exist on type 'Assertion'.
```

I have the package imported in my `hardhat.config.ts`

```
import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle"
```

And I have the package installed:

package.json

```
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.2",
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Pre June 2022

You need to also add `ethereum-waffle` to your package, not just the nomiclabs one  `@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle`.  you need both

```
yarn add --dev ethereum-waffle
```

you just only need to install it, other than that in the hardhat.config.js file this will not be "require" or "import".
menas in `hardhat.config.js` only this will be imported

```js
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle")
```

### Post Just 2022

Hardhat has released a new package named **hardhat-toolbox** to [replace hardhat-waffle](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/migrating-from-hardhat-waffle).

Install it with `npm install --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox` or `yarn add --dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox` and then import it in your `hardhat.config.js` like this:

```
require('@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox')

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: '0.8.9',
  paths: {  },
  networks: {  },
}
```

Once done, you'll be able to use `revertWith` like this:

```
 it('my contract reverting', async () => {
    await expect(myContract.method()).to.be.revertedWith(
      'My revert error message'
    )
  })
```

Comment: but why don't hardhat-waffle has the "revertedWith" ? although hardhat just replicated whole waffle into its package `hardhat-waffle` !!!

Answer (score 4):

Hardhat has released a new package named **hardhat-toolbox** to [replace hardhat-waffle](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/migrating-from-hardhat-waffle).

Install it with `npm install --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox` and then import it in your `hardhat.config.js` like this:

```
require('@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox')

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: '0.8.9',
  paths: {  },
  networks: {  },
}
```

Once done, you'll be able to use `revertWith` like this:

```
 it('my contract reverting', async () => {
    await expect(myContract.method()).to.be.revertedWith(
      'My revert error message'
    )
  })
```

Comment: Awesome, updated my answer with this.

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing this issue as well and most online help weren't addressing the underlying cause.

You also have to add the following to your test files to use event emitters from chai matchers:

```js
const { solidity } = require('ethereum-waffle')
const chai = require('chai');
chai.use(solidity);
```

You can find a more detailed example and explanation [here](https://ethereum-waffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/matchers.html?highlight=events#emitting-events):